# SBT <project name> project refresh failed

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

Whenever I try to enable auto-import in IntelliJ it always gives me this error:

SBT 'mobile-aggregator' project refresh failed

> Error:Error while importing SBT project:[error]   at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1(MainLoop.scala:107)
>   [error]     at sbt.io.Using.apply(Using.scala:22)
>   [error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:101)
>   [error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:57)
>   [error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:42)
>   [error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:34)
>   [error]     at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:113)
>   [error]     at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:76)
>   [error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
>   [error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
>   [error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
>   [error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35) 
>   [error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
>   [error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
>   [error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
>   [error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
>   [error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
>   [error] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.sbt.CreateTasks$ 
>   [error] Use 'last' for the full log.
>   [info] shutting down server
> See complete log in  href="file:/C:/Users/Rahman/.IdeaIC2017.2/system/log/sbt.last.log">file:/C:/Users/Rahman/.IdeaIC2017.2/system/log/sbt.last.log

Comment: Is it possible to check the issue with newer IDEA and Scala plugin versions (2017.3.3 or 2017.3.4)?

Comment: I want to continue doing into these versions only, due to organisation constraints.

Answer (score 0):

This happens quite a few times when your compiler / editor tries to use your cached project data.
To fix this, perform the following steps:

1. Exit IntelliJ & Delete .idea folder from the `root project folder`
2. Delete target folder from `root_project_folder\target` & `root_project_folder\project\target`
3. Make sure you have a valid name for your project name inside `build.sbt`. It should be in the following format: `name := "projectname"`
4. Again start your intelliJ and reinitialize your project.

Hopefully, that should have solved your problem